# How to run a code if in range has non blank cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I got A1:D17 Range. If in my range has blank cells my code works but vice versa it doesn't work.

Please help to find out problem.

And I wrote this code:

```
Sub Example
    Workbooks("Training_VBA Codes").Activate
    Worksheets("Practice 4").Activate
    Range("A1").Select

    If ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = False Then

        ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy

    Else

        Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are working with `.SpecialCells`, you have to be careful. It there is no match found you will get an error.

Try it like this (**UNTESTED**)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then '<~~ Check if there were blank cells found
        rng.Value = 0
        '
        '~~> Rest of the code
        '        
    End If
End Sub
```

**Tip:** Also avoid the use of `.Activate/.Select`. You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to worry about whether there are empty cells or not.  If you are trying to copy a `UsedRange` you could do something as simple as this:

```
AtiveSheet.Range("$A$1:" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address).copy
```

That will copy every cell in the active sheet whether it's empty or not in the `UsedRange` which means if you only have one cell populated at `d20` it will copy everything from `A1:D20`.

Also I think you might have your if statement backwards I think your if condition should be:

```
If ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = True Then
```

If it finds blank cells then set their value.

Comment: R.Roe, thank your answer.

But I didn't just copy. I need to find blank cells on range if I have and put something on those blank cells. The code which I wrote works when I have blank cells. But if on range has no blank it gives error. I try to solve it.